# Return rows based on timestamp respective to their time zone

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timestamp

I have a table in which every row represents a user. I am also storing the user's time zone as text such as 'America/Denver', 'America/New_York' etc.

Is it possible to write a query that would return users for whom their current time of day is between 1 PM to 11 PM respective to their time zone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE usr (
   usr_id serial PRIMARY KEY
,  usr    text NOT NULL
,  tz     text  -- time zone names
);
```

Use the [`AT TIME ZONE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) construct:

```
SELECT *, (now() AT TIME ZONE tz)::time AS local_time
FROM   usr
WHERE  (now() AT TIME ZONE tz)::time BETWEEN '13:00'::time AND '23:00'::time;
```

Including upper and lower bounds 1 PM and 11 PM.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cabf1/3)

Details for `AT TIME ZONE`:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(1196440219),'GMT','America/Denver');

SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_column),'GMT','America/Denver'),'%H') between 13 and 23

Comment: I want the rows that their current time of the day according to the timezone is between 1 PM to 11 PM